# Java - &0xff gives bits from 8 to 31 as 1's

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, steganography, bitwise-and

I have a problem while doing the AND operator using 0xff.

```
public Pixel(int x, int y, int p) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    pixelValue = p;
    A = (byte) ((p>>24) & 0xff);
    R = (byte) ((p>>16) & 0xff);
    R = (byte) (R&0xff);
    G = (byte) ((p>>8) & 0xff);
    B =(byte) (p & 0xff);
    printAll();
}
void printAll() {
    System.out.println("A "+Integer.toBinaryString(A));
    System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(A));
    System.out.println("R "+Integer.toBinaryString(R));
    System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(R));
    System.out.println("G "+Integer.toBinaryString(G));
    System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(G));
    System.out.println("B "+Integer.toBinaryString(B));
    System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(B));
    System.out.println("pixelValue"+pixelValue);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte)(pixelValue)));
}
```

When doing `Pixel p = new Pixel(0,0,2145687240);`
I get

```
A 1111111
127
R 11111111111111111111111111100100
228
G 11111111111111111111111110010110
150
B 11111111111111111111111111001000
200
pixelValue-56
11111111111111111111111111001000
```

Question being, why are R, G and B filled with 1s? and why is A only 7 bits?
why when calling &0xff I get 1111111111111111111111111100100? shouldn't this cancel everything but the first 8 bytes?

Comment: `byte` goes from `-128` to `127`

Comment: Use `Integer.toBinaryString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(B))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bytes go from `0` to `255` inclusive since they can hold `2^8=256` values. That's the unsigned definition, at least.

The question to ask yourself here is: how do negative numbers get represented? The typical method is using something known as the two's complement. The first bit, instead of representing `0` when off and `2^(n-1)` when on, like it usually would, instead represents `0` when off and `-2^(n-1)` when on.

Thus, `228` is stored internally as `11100100`. If you convert this from base 2 you will see that this equals `228`... but only when unsigned.

When signed, the last 7 bits represent `100`. Then, the first bit, instead of representing `128`, instead represents `-128`. Thus, the value is `-28` when signed.

Then, when converting this to an integer, since an integer has 32 bits, then the first bit will represent `-2147483648`, and thus the last 31 bits will need to represent `28 + 2147483648`, which is where `1111111111111111111111111100100` comes from. Thus, the 32 bit representation of `-28` is `11111111111111111111111111100100`.

If you want to actually have `228`, you'd probably want to call `Integer.toBinaryString` on the result of `Byte.toUnsignedInt`, which, as the name suggests, converts it as an *unsigned* number. The issue here is that it's being *signed*, which means that it's `-28`, not `228` like you want.